# Lock screen activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, remoteview, custom-notification

I've been always curious to know how does lock screen notification view works on IMO messenger app?
So I did some research and some articles were saying it's custom notification layout and  part of RemoteView class. So I went through some quick tutorial and gave it a try but still I am not really sure whether I'm going right way. 
So, finally I'm asking over here. Do you guys have any idea/suggestion to any library or any other way that I can come up with following outcome?

**Desire**

[image]

**Result so far**

[image]

Zip file- if you wanna take a look at the code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Y-jPBRm4zyTHZsT09kd3pUU0E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the navigation bar (just a back and home buttons) indicates that this is an Activity, placed above the lock screen with usage of the [FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

The styling where it looks like a dialog can be done by [theming your Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme), probably using something like `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! :D